# Why my setDefaultHostnameVerifier() didn't work for the first time?

Tags: android, security, https

Here is my code:

```
 private void upload() {
      Task task = new Task();
      task.execute();
 }

class Task extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
  try {
    URL mUrl = new URL(HttpUrls.getUrl() + HttpUrls.UPLOAD_IMAGE);
    SSLContext sslContext = Global.getSSLContext(AppConfig.getApplicationContext());
    HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) mUrl
        .openConnection();        conn.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
    conn.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty(Constants.Field.USER_UUID, mProductUuid);
    conn.setRequestProperty(Constants.Field.IMG_TYPE, IMGType.PDT_IMG.name()); 
    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Charset", "UTF-8");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
            "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
    OutputStream output = conn.getOutputStream();
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty2(mImgPath)) {
      output.write(begin(System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg"));
    } else {
      output.write(begin(mImgPath));
    }
    if (mUri != null) {   
      Bitmap bitmap = ImageFactory.getBitmapFormUri(GalleryActivity.this, mUri, true);
      output.write(ImageFactory.bitmapToByteAAA(bitmap));
      try {
        bitmap.recycle();
      } catch (Exception e) {
      }finally{
        if(bitmap!=null && !bitmap.isRecycled()){
          bitmap.recycle();
          bitmap = null;
        }
      }
    } else {
      output.write(ImageFactory.bitmapToByteBBB(mBitmap));
    }
    output.write(end());
    output.flush();
    output.close();
    return IOUtils.toString(conn.getInputStream());
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return "";
  }
}
```

I use the self defined certificate in my server, and I have load the trust.bks in `Gloabal.getSSLContext(Application.getApplicationContext())` ,and I call the upload() method every time I click the upload button.
But it is weird that when I click the upload button for the first time, I get the error "hostname is not verified", which means `conn.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);` in my code didn't work, and when I click the upload button for the second time, it works well, and I upload the file successfully, why? Is it have any delay when I call setDefaultHostnameVerifier()? If it is, how can I make it works for the first time I call upload() method? And can anybody tell me the principle of the method setDefaultHostnameVerifier()?